# How to enqueue only certain commands in cypress?

Tags: cypress

I want cypress to only enqueue and start certain commands, for example, ['visit', 'get'] could be the only ones to enqueue. And any other cypress command should be ignored. Is there a way I can implement that?

Comment: What exactly is your end goal for limiting certain commands to enqueue?

Comment: In my automated testing project, there is a custom command that logs tests user journeys to a specific file. I want to be able to log the user journeys without actually running them. So, I will limit the enqueued commands to only logging commands.

Comment: Could you run a script which would take the Cypress script and comment out all commands that are not visit or get?

Comment: @JonA I thought of overriding the cypress commands that I don't wish them to be executed and make them do nothing (i.e. make them just return null).